# No styles on jsp error page

Tags: css, jsp, servlets, error-handling

I am having some troubles in my practice project.

I have a small media portal project written on Servlets/JSP. In this project I have created some custom exceptions hierarchy to handle situations like "Incorrect password", "Such user is already registered" etc. In Servlets, which throw errors I throw them like this:

```
        if (login.length() == 0) {
        log.error("Login field is empty!");
        throw new EmptyFieldException(i18n.getString("Login_field_is_empty!"));
    }
```

Also I have error page, which looks like this:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1251" isErrorPage="true" import="java.util.ResourceBundle,java.io.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglib.tld" prefix="taglib" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.MediaPortal", request.getLocale());
%>
<html style="height:100%;">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title><%= resources.getString("Login_page")%></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidecolumn">&nbsp</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div><h1><%= resources.getString("You_have_encountered_an_error")%>.</h1></div>
            <div><h3><%= exception.getMessage() %></h3></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidecolumn">&nbsp</div>
        <div id="footer"><taglib:sign/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I throw an exception - all works fine except that error page doesn't load any styles at all! there's just text. But when I go directly to the error pages url - styles are loaded. The problem is that servlet ends with the status code 500 and this code, if I understand right, cancel's style.css file loading.

Anyone, please, point me to the solution of this problem.
Every answer is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add the style with absolute path and not relative. If you are not redirected to the page (the URL in the browser is not the URL you manually check), then the relative path won't work. I guess the error code 500 is correct as you are on the error page.

Comment: Nop, that trick didn't work. I am wondering maybe errors should be handled in some way in the appropriate servlet?
Btw, I discovered that when exception is thrown, page is displayed as it if was error.jsp, but in fact the url in the browser is pointing to the servlet, in which this exception has occured.

Comment: That is why you need the absolute path :) Is `"/css/style.css"` is a valid URI? (that would be the absolute path I guess)

Comment: You configured the error page in the `web.xml`, right?

Comment: Yup, it is. If no exception is thrown - style.css is correctly loaded and the page looks just the way it should.
web.xml is configured.

<error-page> <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> <location>/pages/error.jsp</location> </error-page> </web-app>

Comment: And your other `jsp`s are in the pages folder? What you can do is to debug the html (F12 in IE or in FireFox for the DEV toolbar), so you can see the resources and you might see why is it not loaded!

Comment: Yes, other jsp files are under the same dir. I have tried this already in FF with Firebug. The servlet's response is the status 500, and the loading of style.css on error.jsp is cancelled.

Comment: You might have to include the css in the page, I have no further ideas... The only error pages I have right now have the css in `<style>` elements.

Comment: Ok, I think this is by desgin :) I configured the same scenario and I have the same issue... you might want to try `<style><%@include file="/css/style.css" %></style>`